# how can I generate a random number from 1e-9 to 1e9 with uniform probability in r?

Tags: r, random

I am trying to generate a random number from 1e-9 to 1e9. The very naive idea is to generate a sequence from 1 to 1e18, then divide by 1e9. as following.
but seems not working.

```
set.seed(100)
rand <- sort(runif(10000, min =1, max= 1e18))/1e9
result <- sample(rand, 1)
min(rand) 
max(rand)

# result 664426274
# min(rand) 199051.1
# max(rand) 999853646

rand %>% ecdf() %>%  plot
log(rand) %>% ecdf() %>%  plot
```

the min number is much higher than I expect. Besdies, I checked the plot with `ecdf`. it seems the numbers below 1 is quite limited.
How can I generate a uniform distributed sequence?

[image]

ps, what if I generate the sequence with 2 steps?

```
rand2 <- c(runif(5000)/1e9, runif(5000, min = 1, max = 1e9))
```

it goes in this way.

[image]

rand2 %>% ecdf() %>%  plot
log(rand2) %>% ecdf() %>%  plot

Please advise.

Comment: What were you expecting for the min number? it doesn't sound like you are expecting a uniform distribution. You would expect to get almost no numbers less than 1 if you are uniform between ~0 and 1,000,000,000 with only 10,000 draws

Comment: Did you mean "from 1e-9 to 1e9" or "from -1e9 to 1e9" ?

Comment: If you generate a random number between 0 and 1e9, it's almost always going to be above 1 (only one out of a billion numbers will be below 1). Do you want a log-uniform distribution, where the order of magnitude is evenly distributed (e.g. it's as likely to be in (.1, 1) as in (1, 10) as in (10, 100)?)

Comment: thanks, I am expecting 1e-9 to 1e9.  the 10000 samples is just for reference.

Comment: You need to explain how you expect a non-linear sequence to be linear. (Which, as I wrote this, is the gist of the answer by @FlightOdyssey.)

Comment: Pls find my update in minutes. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Think about it: if you're generating a random number uniformly between 1e-9 and 1e9, what are the odds it will be less than say 1? Well, it would be `1/(1e9 - 1e-9)`, or about one in a billion. So it's quite expected that if you generate only 10000 sample cases you'll never see a result that close to the boundary.

On the other hand, perhaps what you're actually looking for is for the *exponent* to be uniformly distributed between -9 and +9? (Hard to say whether that's true or not, it depends on your use case.) In that case you'd want to pick a uniform x between -9 and 9 and then compute 10^x.

Comment: thanks, I tried this approach, and I will try again.